# CodeIgniter: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to show all product in my database for the specific category with anchor on linked list like this

```
<?=anchor('home/display_category/' . $category='Business', 'Business',[
                    'class' => 'list-group-item'                    
                ]) ?>
```

with function on controller

```
public function display_category($category)
{
    $data['products'] = $this->model_products->find_category($category);    
    $this->load->view('homepage', $data);       
}
```

and in model_products

```
public function find_category($category){
    //Search Record based on category
    $hasil = $this->db->where('category', $category)                          
                      ->get('products');
    if($hasil->num_rows() > 0){
        return $hasil->row();
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

and this the code for displaying the product at homepage

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product):?>                    
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <?=img([
                'src'   =>  'uploads/' .$product->image,
                'style' =>  'max-width: 100%; max-height:100%; height:150px; width:100px;'
            ])?>
            <div class="caption" style="height:420px;">
                <h4 align="center"><?=$product->product_name?></h4>
                <hr>
                <p align="justify" style="height:180px;">   <?=$product->misc?></p>
                <hr>
                <h4 align="center">Rp.  <?=number_format($product->price,0,',','.')?></h3>
                <hr>
                <p align="center">                                  
                    <?=anchor('home/add_to_cart/' . $product->id_product, 'Add to Cart',[
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                        'style' => 'align="center"',
                        'role'  => 'button'
                    ]) ?>
                    <?=anchor('home/product_details/' . $product->id_product, 'See Details',[
                        'class' => 'btn btn-default',
                        'style' => 'align="center"',
                        'role'  => 'button'
                    ]) ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've `print_r` the `display_category` function and I get it right like this

```
Array ( [products] => stdClass Object ( [id_product] => 1 [product_name] => Samsung Galaxy J7 [price] => 4500000 [category] => Business [brand] => Samsung [date_added] => 2015-12-12 [os_type] => Android OS [os_version] => 5.1 [network] => GSM / HSPA / LTE [display_desc] => Super AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors [display_size] => 5.5 [wifi] => yes [bluetooth] => yes [gps] => yes [keyboard] => QWERTY [int_memory] => 16GB [ram] => 1.5GB [battery_desc] => Li-Ion battery [battery_size] => 3000 [color] => White, Black, Gold [camera_primary] => 13 [camera_secondary] => 5 [cpu] => Quad-core 1.4 GHz Cortex-A53; quad-core 1.0 GHz Cortex-A53 Octa-core 1.5 GHz [gpu] => Adreno 405 Mali-T720MP2 [resolution] => 720 x 1280 pixels (~267 ppi pixel density) [misc] => The smartphone jungle can be confusing, but the Samsung Galaxy J7 is surprisingly easy to decipher: J for "affordable price" and 7 for "big screen". This is the lite version of the Galaxy A7, offering semi-premium features but confined [image] => samsung-galaxy-j7.jpg ) )
```

But when I get to the homepage, I get error says **"Trying to get property of non-object"**
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$products is a single row which is of type std object. You tried to access it like as an array. Remove foreach since it is not an array. So in the view you can access like:

```
$products->image
```

instead of

`$product->image`

If you need it in array format, you could use

```
return $hasil->result_array();
```

instead of

```
return $hasil->row();
```

in the model function

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay for pointing out that array format but instead of return $hasil->result_array(); I change it to return $hasil->result(); thanks

Comment: Yes  result_array() return as an associative array. Not as objects array. result() fullfills yours view code